# Can you cast catapult on Tenser's Floating Disk

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Just a thought I had.

I know Catapult restricts the items it can use on to items weighing 1-5 lbs.
Tenser's floating disk doesn't really have a weight mentioned (not sure if we can assume it's weightless though).

Even if, what if we put some weight on it? (Is it and everything on it weightless. Most assuredly not or it wouldn't have a limit right?)
For instance what if we put something small like 2-3 lbs on it, wrap it in a blanket all weighing between 1-5 lbs kind of like a pie.

The other part of this which I'm willing to bet will be the main response is it's considered immobile while the caster is within 20 feet of it. That by itself is fair enough. However, could you do it while you are beyond 20 feet.  After you are more than 20 feet apart it begins to follow you. Thus it is no longer immobile. At this point could you conceivably force it back with catapult?

Comment: Related: [Can Catapult be used on Delayed Blast Fireball?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117409)

Answer (score 7):

## No

The *catapult* spell launches an object. *Tenser's floating disk* creates a horizontal plane of force which is not an object.

> Choose one object weighing 1 to 5 pounds within range that isn’t being worn or carried. The object flies...

.

> This spell creates a circular, horizontal plane of force

---

If you could, though, the immobility would restrict this usage since the specific rule outweighs the general. Similarly, an immovable rod would not be flung per [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115658/catapult-immovable-rod).

Comment: @Rubiksmoose They are in separate books; I don't think you can use block ellipses for that.

Comment: Yup my mistake!